# Pairwise hash functions that are independent from each other

Tags: hash, hash-tables

Is there there a way to build a collection of universal hash functions $H=\{h| h:U\to D \}$ where the values of two hash functions are independent one from another? i.e., $\Pr_{h_1,h_2\in H}(h_1(x)=y  \land h_2(z)=w )=|D|^{-2}$ for each $x,y,z,w\in U$.

Also, is there a term for such collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select $h_1,h_2$ independently at random, then by definition

$$\Pr_{h_1,h_2}[h_1(x)=y \land h_2(z)=w] = \Pr_{h_1}[h_1(x)=y] \times \Pr_{h_2}[h_2(z)=w].$$

If your hash family is universal, then both probabilities on the right-hand side will be $1/|D|$.

In other words, if $H$ is universal, then it automatically follows that

$$\Pr_{h_1,h_2}[h_1(x)=y \land h_2(z)=w] = 1/|D|^2.$$

Every universal collection works -- no extra conditions or requirements are needed.

Comment: Thanks! It is really simple